# Access registered variables in a Jinja template

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have the following jinja2 loop:

```
{% for host in groups['node-all'] %}
{% endfor %}
```

This one works, as I used it before. However I'd like to add the following:

When a directory exists, it should add the following line: `directory exists` inside the above loop. 
I'm using the loop in a `template` in Ansible.

I already got the task to register the value

```
- name: Check if /etc exists
  stat:
    path: /etc
  register: etc_exist
```

I haven't been able to found anything in Google or in the Ansible documentation.
Is someone able to help me out here?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

```
{% if etc_exists.stat.exists %} directory exists {% endif %}
```

Above works :) 
Thanks to Martin Ueding for getting me in the right direction!